# Rails ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL Partitioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, partitioning

I've got a large web app which writes many millions of rows into partitioned tables in PostgreSQL each day (meaning there's a new table for each day's data).

We're using [PostgreSQL's table inheritance and partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) to speed things along:

Due to there being year's worth of data in our DB we can't effectively use insert triggers to route the content to the correct table (the functions are getting very, very long in length).

Long story short, we need ActiveRecord to know which table to `insert` and `update` the data on. BUT, not change the table that is used for selects and other DB tasks.

Obviously it's simple to define the table name for a model, but is it possible to override the table name for just particular actions?

Here's a little more detail:

#### Database:

- **Table:** dashboard.impressions (id, host, data, created_on, etc)
- **Table:** data.impressions_20120801 (inherited from dashboard.impressions, with a constraint of created_on being equal to the tables date)

`Impression.create :host=>"localhost", :data=>"{...}", created_on=>DateTime.now` should write to the `data.impressions_20120801` table, where `Impression.where(:host=>"localhost")` should search on the `dashboard.impressions` table, since that contains *all* the data.

Edit: I'm running PostgreSQL 9.1 and Rails 3.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do Rails so I can't help with the ActiveRecord side, but I can offer a pure Pg fallback solution for if you can't get ActiveRecord to do what you want. It'll cost you a little bit of insert performance so it'll be much better to teach ActiveRecord to do the inserts to the right place.

Personally I'd just do the `INSERT`s directly via the `pg` gem and bypass ActiveRecord completely. If you can't do that, or ActiveRecord does caching that means you shouldn't, try this alternate partitioning trigger implementation.

Instead of explicitly listing every partition in your trigger function, consider `EXECUTE ... USING` for insertion, and generate the partition name using your naming scheme. Something like the untested:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partition_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    target_partition text;
BEGIN
    IF tg_op = 'INSERT' THEN
        target_partition = ( ... work out the partition name ... )
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '||quote_ident(target_partition)||' (col1,col2) VALUES ($1, $2)'
            USING (NEW.col1, NEW.col2);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: We ended up using the `pg` gem and managing the inserts/updates that way - although the function worked well in our testing too.